# Unexpected behaviour of Convert.ToDateTime()

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Consider following code snippet:

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime("06/16/2014 -0:10");
Console.Write (dt.ToString());
Console.ReadKey();
```

The output is `6/15/2014 8:10:00 PM`.

This came up during the testing of web application where time of the day is allowed to be entered manually (date, HH and MM in separate ASP.Net textbox controls) and characters were not initially limited to be only digits (ASP .net validator control accepts "-0" to be an integer in 0..23 range).

Can someone explain the logic how that string is converted to this date/time? I would either expect an exception thrown or "6/16/2014 12:10:00 AM" considering "-0" is the same as "0" ("06/16/2014 0:10" converts to "6/16/2014 12:10:00 AM" as one would expect).

Comment: don't let users insert dates as free text, or at least validate it against a very well defined format. there are about 2 million conflicting ways to represent time and date, you don't want to start figuring out what did the user enter. 01/02/2014 - is this February second or January first?

Comment: Well, everybody is correct in saying that -0:10 is treated as TimeZone offset. If one uses **06/16/2014 00:00 -0:10** as an input string the output is the same. It takes 06/16/2014 as a date, assumes time at midnight since it is not specified (all that in UTC). Then it takes my local time (UTC-4) and adjusts time zone by **-0:10**

Comment: AK_: I agree with what you said. FWIW date is not entered as free text, the textbox for date part is set to read-only and value is captured from jQuery datepicker control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) I think you have set timezone -10 minutes.

```
dateString = "2009-05-01T07:54:59.9843750-04:00";
Convert.ToDateTime(dateString);
//    '2009-05-01T07:54:59.9843750-04:00' converts to 5/1/2009 4:54:59 AM Local time.
```

Answer (score 2):

As @LIUFA already noted, this is the result of first parsing the string followed by a conversion to local time. The `-0:10` is interpreted as -10 minute timezone offset and the time part is not specified at all and thus interpreted as midnight.

To see what happens it's illustrative to first parse the string into a `DateTimeOffset`:

```
> DateTimeOffset.Parse("06/16/2014 -0:10", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
16.06.2014 00:00:00 -00:10
```

And then convert to local time (GMT-4:00 in your case)

```
> time.ToLocalTime()
15.06.2014 20:10:00 -04:00
```

Comment: All of this is correct except you missed that date in output is 6/15 and in original string it is 6/16. My local time is GMT-4

Comment: @JoeSchmoe I'm still not used to AM/PM notation.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the -0 portion of the text is taken as the time zone, which is relative to the local time. That would result in the program taking the local hour and setting the minutes to the ten that was given in the string.